# How to write the name of the text file into the text file using bat?

Tags: batch-file, merge, filenames

I have a problem. I have many text file (.txt). I want to write the name of the corresponding text files inside them and finally merge them. I have lots of them. I cant do it manually, its too time consuming.

Suppose, i have a text file named "windows.txt" and its contents are

```
Windows XP
Windows 7
Windows 8
```

I want their contents to be

```
windows
Windows XP
Windows 7
Windows 8
```

After merging similar files they should look like

```
windows
Windows XP
Windows 7
Windows 8

continents
Europe
Asia
Africa

languages
English
Chinese
```

Please HELP !!

Comment: does `type *.txt` >final.txt do what you want?

Comment: the above command only merges them. i also need the names of the corresponding .txt files inside it

Comment: @npocmaka shows you how to include the filenames to the resulting file. Do you really need the filename to be written into the single files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
echo. >result
for /f %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.txt') do (
 echo.
 echo %%~ni
 type %%i
)>>result
ren result result.txt
```

Pseude-Code for better understanding:

```
turn echo off
delete result file
for all txt files in current directory do:
 print empty line
 print name of textfile without extension
 print textfile
and put it into new file "result"
if done, rename the resulting file
```

Comment: what should i do to print a constant string like **$$** in the start of the **name of the text file**

eg. **$$ name**

Comment: find the line, that writes the filename (it's `echo %%~ni`) and add your string to it: `echo $$ %%~ni`

Answer (score 0):

May be too easy but I think it's valid answer:

```
type *.txt >result 2>&1
ren result result.txt
```

The trick is when `type` is used with list of files or wild cards it prints file names in error stream.And its not redirected to file with `txt` extension to avoid its print too but is renamed at the end.

concerning names of the files written into them (better test it first)

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do ( 
 type %%~na.txt* >%%~na 2>&1
 del  /q /f %%~na.txt
 ren %%~na %%~na.txt
 )
```

**EDIT**

Probably will work if 8.3 notation is enabled:

```
@echo off
ren ????????.txt ???????? >nul 2>&1
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('for %%a in (????????^) do @echo %%a') do ( 

 echo %%#>%%~#_
 rem echo %%~n#_
 type %%~n# >>"%%~#_" 2>nul
 del  /q /f "%%~n#"
 ren "%%~n#_" "%%~n#.txt"
)
```

Comment: it worked totally but there are two returns (enter) after name of the file. And please remove the .txt after the printed name of the file